Nuxt to Next app migration - do I need API Gateway?
We are building an ecommerce app in Nuxt and want to migrate to Next.js page by page, while the service is running.
Currently frontend is served from a docker image in AWS AppRunner.
I see two options here for infra of this:
Setup the second Next.js project in the same docker image and also add nginx to route traffic on the per-page basis
Run the new project in a separate AWS AppRunner instance, and route traffic using AWS API gateway
What is the best one? Did I miss something?
The traffic is relatively low - just one Nuxt instance is in use currently.
